# Where to get gedit themes

Tags: linux, ide, ubuntu, themes, gedit

I need some good gedit theme, where did I get one?

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is this repository (suggested in the comments):

https://github.com/ricardograca/gedit-themes

that is a fork of this one (not updated anymore):

https://github.com/mig/gedit-themes

Comment: The mig/gedit-themes repository seems to be stagnant so I forked and did the necessary modifications to the install script and some themes that had issues. You can find the modified version at https://github.com/ricardograca/gedit-themes